# Contivo mapping analyst, mutliple integer to targer.

Tags: mapping, contivo

I am little bit stuck with contivo mapping analyst 5.6 
issue is that I could not find any function to multiple some source value with another integer value. 
Example

```
If Source exists
Move Source * 3 to Target 
Else 
Move -1 to target 
EndIf
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Compute` method for contivo:

```
If Source exists
compute target = Source * 3
Else 
Move -1 to target 
EndIf
```